# Unable to start android studio due to an Runtime exception

Tags: android-studio

I am getting and exception while launching android studio. any help would be appreciated.  Thank you.

[image: This is the error image]

Answer (score 2):

Please follow these steps to solve

1. Open **bin** folder under the directory where you installed your Android Studio.
2. Find the file **idea.properties** and open it with Notepad++, UltraEdit, or other edit tools.
3. Add **disable.android.first.run=true** as the final line and save the file.
4. Restart Android Studio.

I hope this solution will solve your problem.